# Написал код, а как вывести результат, понять не могу Python

Tags: python, геометрия

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def dist_to(self, other_point):
        return ((self.x - other_point.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other_point.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
        self.point_1 = p1
        self.point_2 = p2
        self.point_3 = p3
    def perimeter(self):
        a = self.point_1.dist_to(self.point_2)
        b = self.point_1.dist_to(self.point_3)
        c = self.point_2.dist_to(self.point_3)
        return a + b + c
    def area(self):
        a = self.point_1.dist_to(self.point_2)
        b = self.point_1.dist_to(self.point_3)
        c = self.point_2.dist_to(self.point_3)
        p = (a + b + c) / 2
        return (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) ** 0.5
figures = [
    Triangle(Point(2, 4), Point(6, 8), Point(-2, 10)),
    Triangle(Point(12, 3), Point(7, 7), Point(0, -10)),
    Triangle(Point(-8, -4), Point(6, -6), Point(6, 10)),
]
```

Этот код считает периметр и площадь заданных треугольников в массиве figures
Вот как можно вывести результат? Функцию пытался вызвать не получается.
Есть идеи?

Comment: print(*(fig.area() for fig in figures), sep='\n')

Comment: Если вы не можете вывести результат, то есть подозрение, что код писали не вы.

Comment: этот код ничего не считает. Но может посчитать, если потребуется.

Answer (score 2):

А где код, как вы пытались вызвать функцию? Всё работает:

```
for fig in figures:
    print(fig.area())
```

Вывод:

```
20.00000000000001
56.49999999999999
112.00000000000006
```